# How to Control PostgreSQL Password authentication both Front end and Command line in Windows 10 and Redhat (Linux)?

Tags: postgresql, redhat

Recently I'm using PostgreSQL9.2 both in Windows 10 and Redhat (Linux). 
But now I'm little concern about PostgreSQL access authentication. 
Late me explain...

When i first installed PostgreSQL in my system i used two different password for two log in role postgres (default) and adempiere (created). In Redhat i use to `psql -h localhost -U postgres db_name` and `psql -h localhost -U adempiere db_name` command. Sometime this command wants password sometime not.

Recently I have used `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';` and `ALTER USER adempiere WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';` command to change. But here is an another problem. After changed my password when i get database access with `psql -h localhost -U adempiere db_name` command, i can access with both `old_passwod` and `new_password`.

Now what can i do for Strong authentication in my Database both Windows 10 and Redhat (linux) ?

Here is part of my pg_hba.conf for reference:

```
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.



# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.2.151/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.2.5/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.2.6/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Can you clarify a few things: 1) which OS is PostgreSQL installed on: RedHat Linux, or Windows 10? 2) Are you running `psql` from RedHat only? 3) Are you running `psql` from the same host where the database is installed? 4) What user account are you logged in as when you run `psql` (I mean the username that you used to log in to the OS)? 5) On RedHat, do you have a file called `$HOME/.pgpass`?

Comment: I'm unsure what windows 10 has to do with any of this, it sounds like everything is happening on RedHat.

Comment: What is in your pg_hba.conf?

Comment: "Sometime this command wants password sometime not"  There is no random element.  A pattern must exist, even if you have not identified it.  Is it asking for a password on Windows, but not from Linux?

Comment: @Z4-tier-- 1. I'm using redhat 6.9 version. 2. Yes, i use `psql` use in command to access database. 3. Yes, i run `psql` run from the same host where the database is installed. 4. I have two user account `postgres` and `adempiere` to log in. 5. I'm confused about `$HOME/.pgpass`

Comment: @jjanes --- I want to configure PostgreSQL that all time when user want to access database system must ask Password.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To force password authentication for every connection, replace `trust` with `md5` everywhere in `pg_hba.conf` and reload the server.

It is dangerously negligent to use PostgreSQL 9.2. Use a later version. For one, this will offer the more secure `scram-sha-256` hashing method for password authentication.